# Replace / Reposition numbers in text <td> element

Tags: javascript, css, string, date, replace

This is a strange question i know but i wanted to try anyway

if you look at this page
http://www.gauzy.com/press.html
you can see that the date column is written backwards
year/month/day

it was done in purpose so it will be sorted correctly, because the sorting is done according to numbers and not as date element, therefore if you write the date regularly this what happen

29/10/18

22/02/17

05/01/18

so my question is, Is there a way using CSS or JS to take the date value and change it? for example take the two first numbers and replace them with the two last numbers?

Thank you all

Comment: Please post the relevant code on which you're facing problem.

Comment: First of all, sorting has nothing to do with CSS. Then there are smart grid libraries that use Date objects as 'raw' data, which show them as text in whatever format is needed, and when sorting is needed the Date object is used. You might want to spend some to see if one exists that fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with javascript :

```
'29/10/18'.split('/').reverse().join('/'); // "18/10/29"
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all i'd give the dates in question a class or something. I used 'date'.

Then try a function like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var dates = document.getElementsByClassName('date');
  for (var i=0; i<dates.length; i++) {
    var date = dates[i].innerHTML.split("/").reverse().join("/");
    document.getElementsByClassName('date')[i].innerHTML = date;
  }
}
```